# Way of skipping first array added by subscription handler

Tags: c#, list, xamarin, events, handler

I have a Bluetooth application that connects to devices and extracts data from them. The data I receive is in the form of byte arrays of size 20. Every time the first array the device sends is an array that contains only general information about the device and not information I want to include in my solution. I was wondering if there is a way for when the device calls the subscription handler the first time, the first array wont be added only the ones after it. I use the xabre Ble plugin in Xamarin. Every time the handler is called I add the bytes to a list of byte arrays.

```
  getDataCharacteristic.ValueUpdated += (o, args) =>
                    {
                        var bytes = args.Characteristic.Value;
                        

                        gatheredInfo.Add(bytes);
                    };

                    await getDataCharacteristic.StartUpdatesAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
 private bool isSecondCall;   

getDataCharacteristic.ValueUpdated += (o, args) =>
      {
          if(!isSecondCall) { 
              isSecondCall = true;
              return; 
          }
          var bytes = args.Characteristic.Value;
          gatheredInfo.Add(bytes);
      };
    
await getDataCharacteristic.StartUpdatesAsync();
```